# How do I get column name of table from specific database?

Tags: sql-server

I wanted to get column name of a table, for that I've used below query, which works fine.

```
select COLUMN_NAME 
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
where TABLE_NAME = 'G001'
```

But now that I want to get column name of table from specific database, for the same  I'm using below query ,but it doesn't giving any output.

In e.g. `HS` is my database name out of multiple databases and `G001` is my table name.

And in my case I need to pass database name and table name as parameter.

```
select COLUMN_NAME 
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
where TABLE_NAME = 'HS..G001'
```

So my question is how do I get column name of table from specific database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` in the database you want to query, eg:

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME 
FROM HS.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE TABLE_NAME='G001'
```

If you need to pass this as a parameter, then you need to write some dynamic SQL:

```
DECLARE @database VARCHAR(255) = 'HS'
DECLARE @table VARCHAR(255) = 'G001'

DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(1000) = 'SELECT COLUMN_NAME 
                              FROM ' + @database + '.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
                              WHERE TABLE_NAME = ''' + @table + ''''

EXEC(@sql)
```

**Note:** Dynamic SQL like this can be vulnerable to SQL injection so make sure you sanitise your inputs.

Comment: Sorry, my fault, I was trying without `.COLUMNS`

Comment: I was not questioning, my English isn't polite enough. I'm sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Simplay put the database name right before like this:

```
select COLUMN_NAME from [<database_name>].INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where TABLE_NAME='G001'
```

Answer (score 0):

just use this:

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME='HS..G001'
  AND TABLE_SCHEMA='database_name'
```